# Why this sort command gives me an empty file?

Tags: terminal, sort

*prova1* is a file with some text.
When I run this code *prova1* become empty:

```
sort prova1 > prova1
```

I know that to achieve the effect I can do:

```
sort prova1 -o prova1
```

I would just know the reason :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the redirection is carried out first: `>prova1` truncates your file so that the `sort` finds nothing. `sort prova1 > prova1_sorted` would work as you expect.

Comment: It might be worth noting that sort's `-o` option probably works around this by creating a temporary file, the same as sed's `-i` option.

Comment: Depends. If sort is sorting in memory, it has to read the whole file to memory before writing anyway. If it's using some kind of merge sort with files it might need more than one temp file, independantly of the output.