# Why does the command shuf file > file leave an empty file, but similar commands do not?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

I know this is sort of a duplicate of another question ([Why this sort command gives me an empty file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97446/why-this-sort-command-gives-me-an-empty-file)) but I wanted to expand on the question in response to the answers given.

The command

`shuf example.txt > example.txt`

Returns a blank file, because the shell truncates the file before shuffling it, leaving only a blank file to shuffle. However,

`cat example.txt | shuf > example.txt`

will produce a shuffled file as expected.

Why does the pipeline method work when the simple redirection doesn't? If the file is truncated before the commands are run, shouldn't the second method also leave an empty file?

Comment: @Gilles The question is more specifically about why the command works in a different format, and has this point has not been answered yet

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that `> example.txt` starts writing to that file, before `shuf example.txt` starts reading it. So as there was no output yet, `example.txt` is empty, `shuf` reads an empty file, and as `shuf` makes no output in this case, the final result stays empty.

Your other command may suffer from the same issue. `> example.txt` may kill the file before `cat example.txt` starts reading it; it depends on the order the shell executes those things, and how long it takes `cat` to actually open the file.

To avoid such issues entirely, you could use `shuf example.txt > example.txt.shuf && mv example.txt.shuf example.txt`.

Or you could go with `shuf example.txt --output=example.txt` instead.

Comment: `> example.txt` doesn't start writing to the file, it opens the file for writing with truncation. Compare with `1<> example.txt` which opens it read-write without truncation.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, opening a file for writing with truncation is usually how you start writing to a file. It's quite hard to do without opening it. ;)

Comment: Your wording is confusing. `> file` doesn't _write_ anything and the real problem is that it truncates. If it only opened for writing (as `1<> file` does), there wouldn't be any problem (at least not with `shuf`).

Comment: If `> file` didn't write anything, it would work on a read-only filesystem. It only doesn't write anything when you take it literally (as in the syscall `write()`). You're riding on technicalities there that IMHO are way more confusing than my simplified explanation.

Comment: `shuf 1<> file < file` is deceptively neat. It works because `shuf` outputs the same amount of data, so all of `file` is overwritten. It would not work with, say, `wc 1<> file < file`. This, however, would: `(rm file; wc > file) < file`

Answer (score 10):

The package [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) has a command `sponge`:

```
   sponge  reads  standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
   Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before  opening
   the output file. This allows constricting pipelines that read from and
   write to the same file.
```

with that way you can do:

```
shuf example.txt | sponge example.txt
```

(*unfortunately the moreutils package also has a util named `parallel` that is far less useful than gnu parallel. I removed the `parallel` installed by moreutils*)

Comment: Don't have `sponge`? Use `(rm foo; shuf > foo) < foo`

Answer (score 2):

You are just quite lucky running

```
cat example.txt | shuf > example.txt
```

doesn't empty `example.txt` like this command is doing.

```
shuf example.txt > example.txt
```

Redirections are performed by the shell before the commands are executed and pipeline components are executed concurrently.

Using the `-o` / `--output` option would be the best solution with `shuf` but if you like taking (very slight) risks, here is a non traditional way to avoid the processed file to be truncated before being read:

```
shuf example.txt | (sleep 1;rm example.txt;cat > example.txt)
```

and this simpler and faster one, thanks to Ole's suggestion:

```
(rm example.txt; shuf > example.txt) < example.txt
```

Comment: This, of course, assumes that 1 second is long enough. It would better to instead use `sponge` or a temporary file.

Comment: @ChrisDown sponge or a temporary file would be definitely more secure, especially with a remote or non inode based file system but in usual cases, 1 second should be long enough for shuf to open the file unless this is a very loaded system.

Comment: Try: `(rm foo; shuf > foo) < foo`

Answer (score 1):

From the GNU `bash` [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation) (see also, for the details, section [3.7 Executing Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Executing-Commands)):

> **3.1.1 Shell Operation**
>
> The following is a brief description of the shell’s operation when it
>   reads and executes a command. Basically, the shell does the following:
>
> 1. Reads its input from a file (see [Shell Scripts](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Scripts)), from a string
>      supplied as an argument to the -c invocation option (see [Invoking
>      Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash)), or from the user’s terminal.
> 2. Breaks the input into words and operators, obeying the quoting rules
>      described in [Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting). These tokens are separated by `metacharacters`.
>      Alias expansion is performed by this step (see [Aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)).
> 3. Parses the tokens into simple and compound commands (see [Shell
>      Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Commands)).
> 4. Performs the various shell expansions (see [Shell Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)),
>      breaking the expanded tokens into lists of filenames (see [Filename
>      Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)) and commands and arguments
> 5. Performs any necessary redirections (see [Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)) and removes
>      the redirection operators and their operands from the argument list.
> 6. Executes the command (see [Executing Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Executing-Commands)).
> 7. Optionally waits for the command to complete and collects its exit
>      status (see [Exit Status](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status)).

Consider the situation where your file does not exist. Yet your second example will create the file *most of the times*. If the file had not been so created and it didn't exist, and redirection hadn't occurred, `cat` would complain there is no such file... Most of the time it won't. To reproduce the shuffle you got with that second command, I needed a great [many tries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110563/how-can-the-order-of-execution-in-the-shell-as-it-relates-to-redirection-be-upse). So indeed the second expression should leave an empty file most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%!shuf' -cx example.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` run command
3. `x` save and close

Comment: Fails if `example.txt` does not end in newline.

Comment: And it is dead slow. 175MB: time shuf ... = 6.2s, time ex ... > 20m.

Comment: Well it does read everything into memory as it is a full editor (generally part of vim)  So I would expect it to be just as slow as if your used vim!

Comment: On the other hand if you need to look at a later part of the file to modify something at the begining!  Then it's probably better than trying to parse the file twice, and safer too.
I have used this for password file modifications to insert new users into it while retaining UID order!     It is also usefull for updating  disk quota using "edquota".

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version I have found:

```
(rm foo && shuf > foo) < foo
```

This opens the file, unlinks it, and then truncates the file. Thereby you avoid the truncated file before opening it, which is what you will normally see when redirecting output to the same file as you are reading from.

Comment: I'd do `(rm foo&&shuf>foo)<foo`. As removing `foo` could fail (that's the permissions to the current directory that matter) while `> foo` could succeed (as it's `foo`'s permissions that matter) resulting in `foo` being truncated and the data lost.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point