# Command line 'buffer'

Tags: bash, files, stdout

I wanted to `tail` the last 100 lines of a file to the same file, but the command
`tail -n 100 file > file` doesn't work, I assume because the stdout gets written to the file 'live', before everything was read from the original file.

Is there some way to pipe the output to *something*, that then keeps it until all 100 lines are there, and then outputs it to the file? Or just another way to shorten the file in this way?

Comment: I wouldn't mark it as a duplicate, as my problem has been wonderfully solved by sponge. Still, the link is good for people (like me) who want to know more about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sponge` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is good for this. It will:

> soak up standard input and write to a file

You use it like this:

```
tail -n 100 file | sponge file
```

to get exactly the effect you want.

Comment: Much nicer than less :) Also, thanks for introducing me to moreutils. That looks very useful. I think I'll accept this one.

Comment: Sponge; I love analogy; great name!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the moment I finally ask the question on SE, the answer comes to me. I think less does what I need, so I just write:

`tail -n 100 file | less > file`

Comment: It's actually the redirection (`>`) that truncates the file, rather than the command you run - this won't (or at least shouldn't!) work. The shell opens and empties the destination before it even starts the commands you give. See the (slightly obtuse) description of output redirection in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02).

Comment: @illuminÉ: That is a neat point. So I should say that this does work very occasionally, but nondeterministically.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Re [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110566/44370): really just an edge case, just thought of sharing it as it was insightful in context! Cheers!

Comment: OK, thanks for telling me. I think I'll downvote my own answer x) EDIT: I can't. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
tail -n 100 file > file
```

The shell forks a process, opens `file` for writing in it, with truncation (that is making it an empty file) and then executes `tail` in that process. To open `file` without truncation, you can use the `<>` redirection operator instead:

```
tail -n 100 file 1<> file
```

The problem though is that there will be no truncation at all. That is, `file` will be overridden with its last 100 lines, but after those `100` lines, what was originally in the file will still be there. So you'd need to call another command to do the truncating after `tail` has finished.

```
{ tail -n 100 file; perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'; } 1<> file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(tail -n 100 file)" > file
```

Comment: Unless any lines contain more than one word or are blank.