# remove lines in file 1 from file 2

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

i do have a text include lines which i would like to delete from my original text.

as example

**Original Text**

```
11
111111111111111111,111111111,11
12,12
99999999999999999,19,1999,199
```

**Text Include Lines to be removed**

```
12,12
99999999999999999,19,1999,199
```

**Expected Output**

```
11
111111111111111111,111111111,11
```

so what is the best solution for that case?

Comment: Seems like a case for grep -xvfF to me

Comment: @JeffSchaller grep -Fxf :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner user `grep`:

```bsh
grep -Fxv -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

This command outputs the lines in `file1.txt` which are not in `file2.txt` - in the order that they appear in.

If you don't care about preserving order, the you can also use the `comm` command:

```bsh
comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

This command outputs the line in `file1.txt` which are not in `file2.txt` -
 in sorted order.

You could also use a while-loop to iterate over the lines of the first file (e.g. `file1.txt`), check each line against the second file (e.g. `file2.txt`) using `grep`, and print the line if it isn't found. This will have the effect of producing the text comprising the lines of `file1.txt` with the lines from `file1.txt` removed. It could look something like this:

```bsh
while read line; do
    if ! grep -qF -- "${line}" file2.txt; then
        echo "${line}";
    fi;
done < file1.txt
```

If you want to write the results to a file you could use output redirection, e.g.:

```bsh
while read line; do
    if ! grep -qF -- "${line}" file2.txt; then
        echo "${line}";
    fi;
done < file1.txt > output.txt
```

The same thing goes for the `grep` and `comm` commands:

```bsh
grep -Fxv -f file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

```bsh
comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) > output.txt
```

**NOTE:** You can't redirect the output back to `file1.txt`. Because of the way output redirection is implemented this will only end up deleting the contents of `file1.txt`. For further discussion of this issue see, e.g. the following post:

- [Why does the command shuf file > file leave an empty file, but similar commands do not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110490/why-does-the-command-shuf-file-file-leave-an-empty-file-but-similar-commands)

If you want to replace the original file you can just overwrite it with the output file, i.e.:

```bsh
mv output.txt file1.txt
```

You could also turn this into a script. Here's a script using the while-loop:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# removelines.sh

# Set filenames
INPUTFILE="$1"
FILTERFILE="$2"
OUTPUTFILE="$(mktemp)"

# Write the lines from INPUTFILE to OUTPUTFILE
# minus the lines from FILTERFILE
while read line; do
    if ! grep -qF -- "${line}" "${FILTERFILE}"; then
        echo "${line}";
    fi;
done < "${INPUTFILE}" > "${OUTPUTFILE}"

# Replace INPUTFILE with OUTPUTFILE
mv "${OUTPUTFILE}" "${INPUTFILE}"
```

And here's the same script using `comm`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# removelines.sh

# Set filenames
INPUTFILE="$1"
FILTERFILE="$2"
OUTPUTFILE="$(mktemp)"

# Write the lines from INPUTFILE to OUTPUTFILE
# minus the lines from FILTERFILE
comm -23 <(sort "${INPUTFILE}") <(sort "${FILTERFILE}") > "${OUTPUTFILE}"

# Replace INPUTFILE with OUTPUTFILE
mv "${OUTPUTFILE}"
```

Note that I use the `mktemp` function to generate a random filename for the output file.

Here's what the script would look like in action:

```
user@host:~$ cat <<HEREDOC > file1.txt
11
111111111111111111,111111111,11
12,12
99999999999999999,19,1999,199
HEREDOC

user@host:~$ cat <<HEREDOC > file2.txt
12,12
99999999999999999,19,1999,199
HEREDOC

user@host:~$ bash removelines.sh file1.txt file2.txt

user@host:~$ cat file1.txt
11
111111111111111111,111111111,11
```

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Sure thing. But check out my updated solution. I added a one-liner using `comm`.

Comment: you forgot to mention that `comm` need files to be sorted firstly, otherwise can be handle through `comm -i <(sort -i test1.list) <(sort -i test2.list)`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Yeah, thanks. I was kind of rushing. I added a third solution using only `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the mentioned result using this awk one-liner

```
$ cat file1
11
111111111111111111,111111111,11
12,12
99999999999999999,19,1999,199
```

```
$ cat file2
12,12
99999999999999999,19,1999,199
```

The following command deletes the contents of file2 from file1

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a ) {print $1}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
11
111111111111111111,111111111,11
```